# Basic hello world server and Xmlhttprequest client -- Status always 0

Tags: javascript, node.js, xmlhttprequest

I'm just starting out messing around with web programming. I have this basic Node.js server that serves "Hello World" with a status code of 200, as well as a client page that receives the request and alerts with the status. The node server:

```
function start(){
    function _handler(request, response){
        console.log("request received");
        response.writeHead(200);
        response.end("Hello World\n");
        console.log("response sent");
    }

    http.createServer(_handler).listen(8080);
    console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8080/');
}

start();
```

and the client javascript:

```
function httpGet(theUrl){
    var xmlHttp = null;
    xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
        alert(xmlHttp.status);
    }

    xmlHttp.open( "GET", theUrl, true );
    xmlHttp.send( null );
}
httpGet("http://127.0.0.1:8080/");
```

But the alert just responds with a status of 0 all three times that the readystate changes. My browser navigating to the server location seems to work fine so the issue appears to be in the client.

Comment: What does the JavaScript error console of your browser say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks fine.

So the issue might be related to cross-domain XMLHttpRequests. You can either add an header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` or disable these security checks in your browser for developing purposes (in Chrome via `--disable-web-security`).

Comment: Access-Control-Allow-Origin fixed it! I'm still confused about what exactly caused this to be blocked; is it still cross-domain from local to local?